# Decompiling an APK using Android Chef

Tags: android, decompiler

I downloaded this program called Android Chef to try to get my lost source code back. Unfortunately every time i run it and point it to my APK file it says generating jar and ends up with an error saying "coundn't decompile" . What could be the reason ?

Also I am sure it is not encrypted as i have tried to decompile with the other tools and was able to but the results were not too good.

Comment: I assume you mean AndroChef. Why not ask the developer? AndroChef is commerical proprietary software, so that's your best bet anyway. Apart from that, you could always try other free tools. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any good public Android decompilers. As a last resort, you can always use Dex2Jar + a Java decompiler, like Procyon, but this is a last resort because Dex2Jar tends to mangle stuff and Java decompilers aren't aware of the patterns that Android code typically has, so the results aren't as good.

Comment: @user3828453 : Can you direct me to the developer link . I did visit the website but was unable to find a help or contact request

Comment: try at_neshkov@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

I might also add, that there is modern alternative to these commercial applicasions or even to the (in)famous free APKTool->dex2jar->JD-GUI route!

Just try open-source APK and DEX decompiler called Jadx: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jadx/files/ 
It has also online version here: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk